# jQuery Fileupload (Blueimp) with AngularJS and Spring MVC

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, spring, file-upload

I'm new to the web development and I'm currently trying to implement a simple file upload for tests purpose.

To sum up, my goal is simply to reproduce this : http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/angularjs.html with Java server side.

Using the jQuery Fileupload plugin and AngularJS I want to make an UI to upload files on a server.
On the server side I'm using Java and Spring MVC to handle HTTP requests.

However, I'm currently unable to make it works, surely because I don't know what kind of HTTP requests I should handle when using jQuery Fileupload with AngularJS, and the Blueimp documentation did not help me (probably my bad, it's maybe something well-known when you are working with this kind of frameworks).

Here is my current AngularJS controller file (it's basically a copy of the one given with the AngularJS example) :

```
/* jshint nomen:false */
/* global window, angular */

(function () {
    'use strict';

    var url = '/ExerciseValidator/upload/';

    angular.module('file-upload', ['blueimp.fileupload'])
        .config([
            '$httpProvider', 'fileUploadProvider',
            function ($httpProvider, fileUploadProvider) {
                delete $httpProvider.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'];
                fileUploadProvider.defaults.redirect = window.location.href.replace(
                    /\/[^\/]*$/,
                    '/cors/result.html?%s'
                );

                angular.extend(fileUploadProvider.defaults, {
                    // Enable image resizing, except for Android and Opera,
                    // which actually support image resizing, but fail to
                    // send Blob objects via XHR requests:
                    disableImageResize: /Android(?!.*Chrome)|Opera/
                        .test(window.navigator.userAgent),
                    maxFileSize: 999000,
                    acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(c|cpp|h|hpp)$/i
                });
            }
        ])

        .controller('FileUploadController', [
            '$scope', '$http', '$filter', '$window',
            function ($scope, $http) {
                $scope.options = {
                    url: url
                };

                $scope.loadingFiles = true;
                $http.get(url)
                    .then(
                        function (response) {
                            $scope.loadingFiles = false;
                            $scope.queue = response.data.files || [];
                        },
                        function () {
                            $scope.loadingFiles = false;
                        }
                    );
            }
        ])

        .controller('FileDestroyController', [
            '$scope', '$http',
            function ($scope, $http) {
                var file = $scope.file,
                    state;
                if (file.url) {
                    file.$state = function () {
                        return state;
                    };
                    file.$destroy = function () {
                        state = 'pending';
                        return $http({
                            url: file.deleteUrl,
                            method: file.deleteType
                        }).then(
                            function () {
                                state = 'resolved';
                                $scope.clear(file);
                            },
                            function () {
                                state = 'rejected';
                            }
                        );
                    };
                } else if (!file.$cancel && !file._index) {
                    file.$cancel = function () {
                        $scope.clear(file);
                    };
                }
            }
        ]);

}());
```

In my view I have a form with `data-ng-app="file-upload"` and `data-ng-controller="FileUploadController"`.

And here is my current Spring controller :

```
@Controller
public class ExerciseValidatorController {

private static final String OUTPUT_FILEPATH = "D:/tmp/";

private final LinkedList<FileMeta> files = new LinkedList<>();

/**
 * Called on index page, returns the file upload page
 * @return the file upload page
 */
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showExerciseValidator() {
    return "FileUploadView";
}

/**
 * Called when files are uploaded, write them to disk and call the validation page
 * @param request the request
 * @param response the response
 * @return TBD
 */
@RequestMapping(value="/upload/", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
LinkedList<FileMeta> postUpload(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) {
    if(!(request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest)) {
        return null;
    }

    Iterator<String> itr = ((MultipartHttpServletRequest)request).getFileNames();
    MultipartFile mpf = null;

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        mpf = ((MultipartHttpServletRequest)request).getFile(itr.next());

        final FileMeta fileMeta = new FileMeta();
        fileMeta.setFileName(mpf.getOriginalFilename());
        fileMeta.setFileSize(mpf.getSize() / 1024 + " kB");
        fileMeta.setFileType(mpf.getContentType());

        try {
            fileMeta.setBytes(mpf.getBytes());

            FileCopyUtils.copy(mpf.getBytes(), new FileOutputStream(OUTPUT_FILEPATH + mpf.getOriginalFilename()));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        files.add(fileMeta);
    }

    return files;
}
}
```

When I use Firebug to test my view, I get the following error : "NetworkError: 405 Method Not Allowed - http://localhost:8080/ExerciseValidator/upload/"

And nothing happens when I try to upload a file: I can select a file in my hard drive, but it is not shown in the list of files that can be uploaded.

I also tried to add a handler for the GET method on /upload/ in my Spring controller. But even though it get rid of the 405 error, I don't know what should I do with this request. Moreover, I did not notice any improvement in the UI: the list of uploadable files did not show up.

Does anyone have an idea of what should I do ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Javascript file, the controller was defined with the name FileUploadController, but this controller's name is already defined in jquery.fileupload-angular.js. Changing it to InternalFileUploadController (for instance) solved the problem.